# fetch option input value by table row

Tags: php, html

I have this issue that drives me crazy. I am working on a project for customer contracts management and now that I have to edit their data I may need to change data or keep the one that's existing.

[Here's my data table. There we have a customer, his plan and term.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GteiE.png)

I am able to fetch non-list values. But when it comes to listed ones, I have no idea how to fetch the assigned value by row.

[Edit page, the list comes up and selected data saves, but I don't want it to be blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qSsh.png)
Code for listed values:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Klientas<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
         <select class="form-control" id="val-skill" name="name" required="">
            <option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"></option>
           <?php  
                    $c1 = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_customer`";
                    $result = $conn->query($c1);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
                                <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    } else {
                    echo "0 selections";
                        }
                    ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for non-list values which works properly:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-digits">Data nuo<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="val-digits" name="fromdate" value="<?php echo $fromdate; ?>" placeholder="" required="" onchange="calculate();" onkeyup="calculate();">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### It seems like you want to get an associative array instead of a numerical one, which would require the following change:

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

### should be

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

### This will return the data in the format that your code will be able to interface with.

Comment: It didn't work, still the same. No fetch value, same option list. Any more ideas?

Comment: put `print_r($result);`   after `$result = $conn->query($c1);`   and you will  get a better idea of how the data is being returned (if at all)

Comment: I am afraid, a still no do, tried different variations.

Comment: you have $row["id"] before you even make the query

Comment: on line 5 of your code remove `<option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"></option>`

Comment: can you put in enough of the code for someone to be able to reproduce the issue?  have you looked at the error log yet? what happens when you do var_dump($result) ?